# Spring boot + Hibernate - technical questions

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have some questions about Spring Boot and Hibernate.

I discussed with one developer and he said me he  compile his Rest Api, developed with Spring Boot, in Jar and used the tomcat server provided by Spring Boot and deploy the jar on the server. But in my case, i use the war packaging and i deploy on my tomcat server but he said it’s less performing.

I don’t know why and i asking me if you developed in microservices your Resp Api with Spring boot and you use his solution, do you create multiple tomcat instance ?

About hibernate, i used HQL for some queries and he said me it’s bad way because it’s dangerous with Sql injection, it’s true ?

I need some answers of people who can advice me.

Sorry if my english, it’s not great and thank you very much, in advance, for your answer.

Comment: to be honest your question is asked in a bad way, not because of your english but more about how you are asking.  Give more background information, ask in more concise way, and ask in separate question for different problem.  Without more information from you, here is what I can tell: 1. Spring Boot application usually starts with its own embedded web container (e.g. Jetty, Tomcat etc). Therefore yes, there will be multiple web container (i.e. tomcat-equivalents)  2. HQL has nothing to do with SQL Injection directly, but how you write the query has more to do with it.

Comment: Ok sorry, it's my first post but i noted my future topics. Thanki you very much for your answer. i understand better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Java Cloud space there are 2 major directions:

**Java EE**:

1. Create a Docker base image which includes a Java EE application/ web server such (e.g. Tomcat, WildFly, GlassFish,...)
2. Create a (thin) WAR file
3. Create a Docker image based on your base image which deploys the WAR file to the application server

**Spring Boot**:

1. Create a single JAR file using the Spring Boot Maven Plugin
2. Create a Docker image which executes the JAR file

I guess you could also mix the two approaches (create a Spring Boot WAR file), but the single JAR file approach is much more common with Spring Boot (I'm currently using this approach).

Some Java EE experts such as Adam Bien promote the first approach (less dependencies, smaller WAR files, smaller Docker images, more standard APIs (though what "standard" means is currently changing with the transition from Java EE to Jakarta EE)).

I can't tell you which one has a higher performance. Either way there will be one server started per Docker image.

Regarding Hibernate and SQL injection:
I'm not using HQL but JPQL, but in the end it's more or less the same as with JDBC: Don't string concatenate queries with input from the user. Always use some kind of prepared statements with variables to format the user input.

Comment: Hello Puce and thank you,

I understand better. It's my first approach of Spring boot and i didn't know. 
I know Spring MVC and usually i use a WAR file to deploy my app but your explanation is very clear and thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

If you are using spring boot you implement more or less a standalone application (even if it´s a webapplication), therefore yes there will be an own embedded tomcat, jetty, whatever instance for each spring boot application.
SQL injection has nothing to do with the way how you deploy an application, it´s only a question how you create your HQL queries.

However, that´s an interesting discussion. In our company we are quite old fashioned and create an WAR file of our webapplication, and deploy it on our Glassfish server where serveral other web applications are running under the same instance.

Florian

Comment: Thank you very much Florian for your answer